# Having problems with SharePoint Server 2010 Search (not FAST)

Tags: search, error

We have a 2 server test 2010 environment  (WFE, SQL).  Both are x64 Server 2008.  All prereq's installed and service packs.

SharePoint installed fine.  All Service applications were created successfully.  We have two accounts in use (an install account used to run installation, and sp_farm account used to run all services)

When we navigate to C.A. > Search Service Application > Search Administration

we see:

> System Status
>
> Crawl status The search service is not
>   able to connect to the machine that
>   hosts the administration component.
>   Verify that the administration
>   component
>   '8d5c3da9-d70c-41f3-88af-32a4d142aaf4'
>   in search application 'Search Service
>   Application' is in a good state and
>   try again.

**In the event log:**

> The administration component for
>   application Search Service Application
>   failed with exception
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0xC0041235): The gatherer application
>   could not be mounted because the
>   search administration database schema
>   version does not match the expected
>   backwards compatibility schema
>   version. The database might not have
>   been upgraded.      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi.RunVoidOnServer(VoidCodeToRun
>   remoteCode, VoidCodeToRun localCode,
>   Boolean useCurrentSecurityContext,
>   Int32 versionIn)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi.MountApp(String
>   gathererApplicationName)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.SynchronizeAdminComponent(SearchServiceApplication
>   application)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()

This is extremely frustrating.  We rebuilt the environment using only one account only to see the same results.  I've been searching the web all morning for help on this and haven't found anything.  Do you all have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up rebuilding the environment with a Win Server 2008 SPLA license instead of MSDN and search began working.  I was able to get into the crawl settings and logs in Central admin.  I was also able to run a full crawl and get search results back.  I'm not sure what the OS license issue was exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my version of this error - see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/d0eb9d50-1a6e-4e8a-b00a-17800930c90a/

Answer (score 0):

Add Service account to securityAdmin  Role on Database.